# Optimization of price

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, simplex, operations-research

I have following: M resoruces N services, P records where 0 < M,N,P 
Record - is a pair of service (with duration), resource.

So, I need to propose best prices for less busy resources. How to compute this?

Sample: I have a car box where I am washing cars.

> Working day from 8.00-20.00
>
> 30 Min cost normally 10 $.

Based on historical data, I can tell that:

> Probability 0.9 that car came to wash  from 8.00-10.00, 15.00-19.00
>
> Probability 0.6 that car came to wash  from 10.00-11.00
>
> Probability 0.3 that car came to wash  from 11.00-15.00

I want to set discount where low probability, to maximize load actually, for example:

> 10.00-11.00 will cost 6$ - to maximize outcome, increase load
>
> 11.00-15.00 will cost 4$ - to maximize outcome, increase load

Comment: If it's simple enough to put into Excel, do that, then optimize the parameters using Excel's Solver.  If it's too much for Excel, then you'll need to describe the complicating factors.

Comment: @Nat I want to solve it by computer.

Comment: Excel's a computer program.  Do you mean that you want to use a programming language and write your own calls to an existing API?  Or write your own simplex implementation?

Comment: You're right that this problem can be expressed as an LP. You are, however, going to explain your question a bit more clearly. When you have done that, we can look at how to express it as an LP. Solving that LP can be done in a number of ways. Do you have suitable software for solving an LP or do you want to build that from nothing?

Comment: @tomi I've updated sample

Comment: That's better, but leaves a few questions you need to clarify. What do you mean by the probabilities you have given? Are they the probability that in the next 30 minutes there will be a car requiring a wash? You also need to know how the probabilities will change if you change the price. Increasing the price may decrease the probability of a car coming for a wash so you could make things worse! Seriously, you need a model for how demand will depend on the price,